# Importing ObjC files into Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to import files from [this library](https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView), I copied and pasted the following `.h` and `.m` files from the ObjC library into my Swift project:

- `AppDelegate.h`  `AppDelegate.m`
- `ViewController.h`  `ViewController.m`
- `SPUserResizableView.h`  `SPUserResizableView.m`

Upon copying and pasting these files into my project, Xcode asked me to create a bridging header file, I then put the following lines into that bridging header file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SPUserResizableView.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

I tried to build my project, but build failed. I got many `unknown type` errors and such, which I assume is because the system is not recognizing the ObjC code. I also got this line of error:

```
failed to emit precompiled header '....../Project-Bridging-Header-swift_24D19ORYKRN0-clang_1KQCLSEAC5RDY.pch' for bridging header '......./Project-Bridging-Header.h'
```

How do I resolve these errors? What else do I need to do to use the Objective C library in my swift code?

Comment: You don't have to import `UIKit` and `Foundation` through bridging header...

Comment: It seems your precompiled header could not been compiled. Show us your precompiled header.

Comment: Have you checked the **Installation** part of **How To Use It** of the README.md? You do not need `AppDelegate.h/.m` and `ViewController.h/.m`. Those are for the sample project. And the bridging header should be `#import "SPUserResizableView.h"` only. But you need to fix some more parts in `SPUserResizableView.h`. I wonder if such ill-formed code really works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Why you import AppDelegate.h and other

just use this class (SPUserResizableView.h SPUserResizableView.m)

and in Bridge file

^     #import "SPUserResizableView"

Comment: I deleted everything but SPUserResizableView and the bridge file. Things still don't work.

Comment: Check Build setting path   * Targets > [Your App Target] > Build Settings > Swift Compiler - Code Generation > Objective-C Bridging Header:

$(SRCROOT)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/$(PROJECT_NAME)-Bridging-Header.h

Answer (score 0):

in your BridgingHeader just add

```
#import "SPUserResizableView.h"
```

dont copy other projects AppDelegate and ViewController. just copy SPUserResizeableView.h and .m file